# Will installation of macports automatically install or update OpenSSL?

Tags: macports, openssl

I am a mac user and want to stay with the system-provided version of OpenSSL, which is OpenSSL 0.9.8y. I am wondering if installation of macports will automatically update my OpenSSL or install another version?

Also, how can I check the version of the OpenSSL library on my mac instead of the version of the OpenSSL command? Do they always have the same version? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MacPorts will not replace your system-provided version of OpenSSL. If you install OpenSSL using MacPorts, it will do so in a separate prefix (by default `/opt/local`).

To check the version of the OpenSSL library, run `/path/to/openssl version` where `/path/to/openssl` is the path of the OpenSSL binary that corresponds to the library you want to check, e.g. `/usr/bin/openssl` for the system OpenSSL in `/usr/lib/libssl.dylib` and `/opt/local/bin/openssl` for the MacPorts OpenSSL in `/opt/local/lib/libssl.dylib`.

You can also check the OpenSSL library version directly using

```
$> strings /path/to/libssl.dylib | grep -E '^OpenSSL'
```

e.g. for MacPorts:

```
$> strings /opt/local/lib/libssl.dylib | grep -E '^OpenSSL'
OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
```

and for system OpenSSL:

```
$> strings /usr/lib/libssl.dylib | grep -E '^OpenSSL'
OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
```

Unfortunately OpenSSL has changed and those command don't work the ^ in the grep does not find the version so for Macports

```
strings /opt/local/lib/libssl.dylib | grep -E 'OpenSSL'
```

gives

```
!(29OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021
OPENSSL_DIR_read(&ctx, '
OPENSSL_init_ssl
```

and the system library has moved in Big Sur and possibly earlier

Answer (score -1):

MacPort will only install binaries you asked him to install using `sudo port install`.

To know your openSSL version, just type `openssl version`.